# Manipulation of data in database using DML statements as a whole not partially

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions, android-volley

I have a list of items stored in a **ArrayList**, and i am sending them from android app onButton Submit to the **MySql Database** using **Volley Library**. It works fine when internet is working fine, but problem arises whenever internet connectivity issue comes during process. **If during the process of insertion and deletion, issue of internet arises some time it sends all records some time it sends half or some time no items to database. This thing makes my data inconsistent.**

I want to know that is there any way by which a data can be inserted as a whole not partially, i mean that if during DML Process(insert, update, delete) internet issue or any other issue arises which breaks connection to DB then whole query must be rollback. **In more simple words i want to send/ update/ records as a whole not partially. Query execution should be atomic in nature.**

Comment: This mysql database, is it your local db or located on some remote server and could you please put some code too?

Comment: It is not localdb, it is remote.